# Looping through multiple named ranges and going to similar named range VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to check multiple named ranges for a boolean `True/False` value. I need to check the 1-cell validation ranges (*in order*) and if the result is `True`, I need to `.Select` the corresponding named range (i.e., the named range without the corresponding `"validation_"` prefix and exit the subroutine. The following code works, but it's not DRY.

Here's a snippet to get the gist of the question, but this `If-ElseIf` continues for many other named ranges:

```
If Range("validation_name") = True Then
    Range("name").Select
    Exit Sub
ElseIf Range("validation_category") = True Then
    Range("category").Select
    Exit Sub
ElseIf Range("validation_subcategory") = True Then
    Range("subcategory").Select
    Exit Sub
' ... and many more...
```

**Possibilities/Questions:**

- I think I could utilize either an array of named ranges and an array of resulting "go-to" named ranges?
- Perhaps I could use a `collection` instead?
- Not sure if a `for` loop or a `while` loop would be better?

Comment: If you are examining the cells in a range, you do want to test if **any** cell contains *TRUE* or if **all** cells contain *TRUE* ???

Comment: @Gary'sStudent There is a separate named range that will check for if **any** cell contains *True* -- that issue is handled upfront. Then, what I need to is check *in order* these validations so that I can go to the first failed cell; edited question to clarify. Think filling out a form and then sending the user to the *first point* of failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some "extra dry" codes

```
Sub main()
    Dim a As Variant
    For Each a In Array("name", "category", "subcategory")
        If Range("valid_" & a).Value = True Then
            Range(a).Select
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next a
End Sub

Sub main2()
    Dim r As Range, f As Range        
    Set r = Union(Range("validation_date"), Range("validation_name"), Range("validation_subcategory"), Range("validation_category"))
    Set f = r.Find(what:="true", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then Range(Replace(f.name.name, "validation_", "")).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I like the Range.Find approach. The Union can probably be shortened to `Set r = Range("validation_date,validation_name,validation_subcategory,validation_category")`

Comment: @ user3598756 works for me in Excel 2007. In Excel ranges comma is union and space is intersect. This also worked `Set r = [IF(validation_name,name,IF(validation_category,category,A1))]`

Answer (score 3):

I assume that these are 1-cell ranges. If so, the following should work:

```
Sub SelectRange()
    Dim i As long, A As Variant
    A = Array("validation_name", "validation_category", "validation_subcategory")
    For i = 0 To UBound(A)
        If Range(A(i)).Value = True Then
            Range(Split(A(i),"_")(1)).Select
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through all of the named ranges with something like:

```
Dim xlName As Name
For each xlName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If xlName.Name Like "validation_*" And Range(xlName.Name) = True Then
        Application.Goto Replace(xlName.Name, "validation_", ""), True
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next
```

or specify them like this

```
For each strName In Split("name category subcategory")
    If Range("validation_" & strName) = True Then
        Application.Goto strName, True
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next
```

**Update**

Sorry, I did not read the whole question. Seems like you can use some kind of key - value Collection

```
pairs = Array( Array( "validation_name", "name" ), _
               Array( "validation_category", "category" ), _
               Array( "validation_subcategory", "subcategory" ) )

For each pair In pairs
    If Range( pair(0) ) = True Then
        Application.Goto pair(1), True
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next
```

Comment: but that way you're not sure to get the _first_ named range whose value is "True"

Comment: I agree with @user3598756, the first approach is likely to have unintended consequences and does not guarantee the *first* match. Further, there are other "validation_\*" names that I would *not* want to match. Nevertheless, it is an interesting approach to consider for other cases.